# Start AWS instance on queue change

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS-hosted website, which takes images for processing, and adds them to the SQS. Is it possible to automatically start the processing instance whenever there is something in the queue using AWS services, or should I do it manually in my backend's code?

Comment: "automatically start the processing instance" means can you elaborate what instance is it and more details about your website where it it hosted and all?

Comment: @error2007s my website is hosted on AWS, and I want to always keep online t2.micro/t2.nano instance (due to low number of visitors), and run a beefy instance only when needed.

Comment: can you have a lambda run the processing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use EC2 and SQS in conjunction. Please go through this blog https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1464

Comment: So, as my question states, do it manually in my backend's code?

Comment: Yes you can automate this process by writing a script for this in your backend code and use AWS Cli to launch the instance.